# hibernate does not generate on delete cascade in mysql for mapping of a HashMap

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hashmap, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have a problem generating a mysql schema with hibernate. I've searched for an answer to my problem but I haven't found it (many similar problems but not exactly mine).

I need to map a State diagram into mysql (or transition table), and delete the states in cascade. A State may have many States as children (many to many relationship). I succeeded in mapping the State class and the "next state" relationship, but not in generating the correct SQL option ON DELETE CASCADE.

The Java class is as follows:

```
public class State {
private Integer version;
private Integer oid;
private String name;
private Map<String, State> nextStates;

public State(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.nextStates = new HashMap<String, State>();
}

/**
 * Adds some state to the transitions table. 
 * The table is indexed by states names.
 * 
 */
public void addNextState(State s) {
    this.nextStates.put(s.getName(), s);
}
(...)
```

The hibernate configuration is :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/testStatesDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>     
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>       
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <mapping resource="State.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the State mapping is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="State" table="state" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="oid" column="OID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <version column="version" name="version" unsaved-value="null"/>     

    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>

    <map name="nextStates" table="nextStates" cascade="delete" optimistic-lock="true"> 
            <key column="parentState_oid" /> 
            <index column="children_stateName" type="java.lang.String"/> 
            <many-to-many column="children_oid" class="State" /> 
    </map>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

which creates the following schema:

```
Hibernate: 
create table nextStates (
    parentState_oid integer not null,
    children_oid integer not null,
    children_stateName varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (parentState_oid, children_stateName)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Hibernate: 
create table state (
    OID integer not null,
    version integer not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (OID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

Hibernate: 
alter table nextStates 
    add index FKB4A102D5587BDC23 (parentState_oid), 
    add constraint FKB4A102D5587BDC23 
    foreign key (parentState_oid) 
    references state (OID)

Hibernate: 
alter table nextStates 
    add index FKB4A102D5F71F7FB (children_oid), 
    add constraint FKB4A102D5F71F7FB 
    foreign key (children_oid) 
    references state (OID)
```

As an example, consider running the following test code,

```
State pend   = new State("Pending");
State dev   = new State("In development");
State finali = new State("Finalized");

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

pend.addNextState(dev);
dev.addNextState(finali);
dev.addNextState(pend);

session.save(pend);
session.save(dev);
session.save(finali);
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.beginTransaction();
dev = (State)session.load(State.class, 3);
session.delete(dev);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get the following error message:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testStatesDB`.`nextstates`, CONSTRAINT `FKB4A102D5F71F7FB` FOREIGN KEY (`children_oid`) REFERENCES `state` (`OID`))
```

and if I go to the database and add the property ON DELETE CASCADE to the generated foreign keys, the example works as I need.

The question is: Is this the correct way of mapping a many to many relationship using HashMaps? And if it is correct, how do I generate the ON DELETE CASCADE option with an hibernate xml mapping?

I've been dealing with this problem for a long time, but I didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've partially solved the problem: I used a bidirectional relationship between classes State and State (yes, recursive relationship worked). In each State I have a map for the next states in the graph and another for the parent states.

The delete="cascade" option didn't generate the ON DELETE CASCADE as I would have desired, but, as long as I keep the collections inside the states synchronized, I can delete in cascade. By "synchronized" I mean that if a state S1 has S2 as next state, then if you delete the next state S2 in S1, you also have to let S2 know that S1 is no longer its parent.

I hope this help someone... I got stucked for a long time with this problem.

Thank you.
Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

you can set the on delete cascade on the key

```
<key column="parentState_oid" on-delete="cascade" />
```